# why is this button useless after 1 click?

Tags: javascript, html

I want to add a div (with class="book-card") each time I click the button (with class="add-book-btn". With the code below, when i click the button for first time, it works. But then the something is wrong and the button seems it's not working.

HTML:

```
<fieldset class="self">
  <legend class="self-title">curently reading</legend>
  <button class="add-book-btn"><i class="fas fa-plus plus-icon"></i></button>
</fieldset>
```

JS:

```
const selfs = document.getElementsByClassName("self");
const addBookBtn = document.getElementsByClassName("add-book-btn");


addBookBtn[0].addEventListener("click", function() {
    selfs[0].innerHTML += `<div class="book-card"></div>`;
    console.log(selfs[0]);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Using the code of @Dylan Cadd and focusing on my elemnts it worked. But I can't understand what's the differece

JS:

```
const selfs = document.getElementsByClassName("self");
const addBookBtn = document.getElementsByClassName("add-book-btn");


addBookBtn[0].addEventListener("click", function() {
    let innerDiv = document.createElement('div');
    innerDiv.className = 'book-card';
    selfs[0].appendChild(innerDiv);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```js
const selfs = document.getElementsByClassName("self");

function add_card() {
  const addBookBtn = document.getElementsByClassName('add-book-btn');
  addBookBtn[0].addEventListener('click', function(){
    selfs[0].innerHTML += `<div class="book-card"></div>`;
    console.log(selfs[0] );
    
    add_card();
  });
};

add_card();
```

```html
<fieldset class="self">
  <legend class="self-title">curently reading</legend>
  <button class="add-book-btn">Click</button>
</fieldset>
```

Answer (score -3):

I found a solution that is working for me.  Instead of editing the `innerHTML`, I am dynamically creating the div with the classname and appending it to the main fieldset.

```
const selfs = document.querySelector(".self");
const addBookBtn = document.querySelector(".add-book-btn");


addBookBtn.addEventListener("click", function() {
    let innerDiv = document.createElement('div');
    innerDiv.className = 'book-card';
    selfs.appendChild(innerDiv);
    console.log(selfs);
});
```

This solution works for me, let me know if it doesn't for you

Comment: You can't add an event listener to a `NodeList`.

Comment: As you can see this isn't the whole html. I want to have multiple fieldset like that

Comment: @leech I updated my answer with a snippet that I got working for myself

Comment: This is working, because in this html there is only one fieldset and one button. Imagine having 2 fieldsets, how am i gonna add the event listener there?

Comment: @leech I can't comment on posts yet but the reason that probably works is because you can't append a whole div to an element using `.innerHTML`, the DOM doesn't like it, but you can dynamically create them and append it nicely without throwing errors