# onchange function isn't defined when I use string templates

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to create a function that is called when the input value change. The input is created when I click the button. I'm trying to use `onchange` attribute for the input, but hen I edit the value of the first input field I get this error: `addTitle is not defined at HTMLInputElement.onchange`. I don't understand why the function isn't defined.

HTML:

```
<div id="self-container">
            <fieldset class="self">
                <legend class="self-title">curently reading</legend>
                <button class="add-book-btn"><i class="fas fa-plus plus-icon"></i></button>
            </fieldset>
            <fieldset class="self">
                <legend class="self-title">want to read</legend>
                <button class="add-book-btn"><i class="fas fa-plus plus-icon"></i></button>
            </fieldset>
            <fieldset class="self">
                <legend class="self-title">read</legend>
                <button class="add-book-btn"><i class="fas fa-plus plus-icon"></i></button>
            </fieldset>
        </div>
```

JS:

```
const selfs = document.getElementsByClassName("self");
const addBookBtn = document.getElementsByClassName('add-book-btn');

let myBooks = [];

function createBook(title, author, rating) {
    let book = {};
    book.title = title;
    book.author = author;
    book.rating = rating;

    return book;
}

function addTitle(title) {
    console.log("The title is " + title);
}

for (let i = 0; i < addBookBtn.length; i++) {
    
    

    function addBookCard() {
            addBookBtn[i].addEventListener('click', function () {
                myBooks.push(createBook());
                selfs[i].innerHTML += `
                <div class="book-card bc-display">
                    <input type="text" placeholder="title" onchange="addTitle(this.value)">
                    <input type="text" placeholder="author">
                    <input type="text" placeholder="rating">
                </div>
                `;
                addBookCard();
            });
        };
    addBookCard();
}
```

Comment: why you have defined the function inside the `loop`?

Comment: @BadPiggie first i tryed it without the loop, but for some reason the + button didn't work after the first click. So, I had to use the loop to redine he eventListener

Comment: You should not define a function inside the loop.

Comment: @BadPiggie then what should I do? So the button still works. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68416595/why-is-this-button-useless-after-1-click/68416757#68416757

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a cleaner way to achieve this:

**HTML CODE:**

```
<div id="self-container">
  <fieldset class="self">
    <legend class="self-title">curently reading</legend>
    <button class="add-book-btn"><i class="fas fa-plus plus-icon"></i></button>
  </fieldset>
  <fieldset class="self">
    <legend class="self-title">want to read</legend>
    <button class="add-book-btn"><i class="fas fa-plus plus-icon"></i></button>
  </fieldset>
  <fieldset class="self">
    <legend class="self-title">read</legend>
    <button class="add-book-btn"><i class="fas fa-plus plus-icon"></i></button>
  </fieldset>
</div>
```

**JS CODE:**

```
const selfs = document.getElementsByClassName("self");
const addBookBtn = document.getElementsByClassName('add-book-btn');

let myBooks = [];

function createBook(title, author, rating) {
  let book = {};
  book.title = title;
  book.author = author;
  book.rating = rating;

  return book;
}

function addTitle(title) {
  console.log("The title is " + title);
}

function onButtonClicked(index) {
  let html_string = `
                <div class="book-card bc-display">
                    <input type="text" placeholder="title" onchange="addTitle(this.value)">
                    <input type="text" placeholder="author">
                    <input type="text" placeholder="rating">
                </div>
                `;
  selfs[index].insertAdjacentHTML("beforeend", html_string);
};

for (let i = 0; i < addBookBtn.length; i++) {
  addBookBtn[i].addEventListener('click', function() {
    onButtonClicked(i)
  }, false);
};
```

**LIVE DEMO:**
https://jsfiddle.net/h1a92jg7/1/

Comment: It's working perfectly on jsfiddle, but for some reason I still get the error when I run it from VS code

Comment: I had ` type="module"` as a `script` attribute. I deleted and now its working